# MSSQL 2012 intermittent issues with Shared Memory Provider

Tags: sql-server

I am having issues that we've never had in years. All of a sudden this past week we have been getting signs of the database locking up and it would require a full restart of the MSSQL service.

I have also been noticing when we have to manually force things out in studio I get this error back in red:

```
    A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server.       (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)
```

Would anyone know what this is and what could be causing it? I looked at other threads and saw recommendations included AV software which we do not have on the server and I am RDC into the server using studio on the server desktop. I see some plans of action but then I see they may not be related to my issue. I am hesitant because it is such an important component of our system.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any related messages in the SQL Server error log?

Comment: `signs of the database locking up` -> can you be a bit more specific here?

Comment: We have pages timing out and other calls being locked. I think it all starts with the transport-level error. Thanks

Comment: "Calls being locked" does not mean it is anything other than garden variety blocking. What else have you looked at?